Why do I get bus-error with an unused FILE pointer?
I am trying to write a function to read out 2 files with fgets and print them to stdout:
void merge_files(){
    FILE *in1, *in2, *out;
    char *inName1 = "Text_4_input1.txt";
    char *inName2 = "Text_4_input2.txt";
    char *buffer;
    int n = 100;
    if ( (in1 = fopen (inName1, "r")) == NULL ) {
       printf ("Can't open %s for reading.\n", inName1);
    }
    
    if ( (in2 = fopen (inName2, "r")) == NULL ) {
       printf ("Can't open %s for reading.\n", inName2);
    }
    while (fgets (buffer, n, in1 ) !=  NULL)
    {
        fputs (buffer, stdout);
        if ( fgets (buffer, n, in2) != NULL )
        {
            printf ("a");
            fputs (buffer, stdout);
        }
    }
    while (fgets (buffer, n , in2 ) !=  NULL )
    
        fputs (buffer, stdout);
        
    fclose (in1);
    fclose (in2);
}

I always get bus error when running it, and figured out that my FILE *out is never used. If I remove it from my code, then it will work as expected. Why?

char *buffer never gets assigned to anything - it has an indeterminate value.

char *buffer; has no memory allocated. The loop seems strange anyway, making multiple calls to fgets .

Aside: when you check in1 and in2 you report a problem but carry on anyway :(

How strange is undefined behaviour? FILE *out is never used. If I remove it from my code then it will work as expected. The unassigned value of char *buffer; happened to have accessible memory. Please crank up the compiler warnings, to get info about uninitialised variables.

As usual: your compiler would have warned about this. warning: 'buffer' may be used uninitialized

Thanks for all comments. I compiled the code with gcc on MacOs actually it doesn't show me any warning at all. That why I'm so confused. I just cleaned up the code and removed the FILE *out and it works. You guys enlighten me now.

printf ("Can't open %s for reading.\n", inName2); is slightly better than the usual error message, but it's still not sufficient.  Why was the system unable to open the file?  Provide that information, and write it to the proper stream.  (All errors messages belong on stderr.)  You can accomplish both by replacing the printf with perror(inName2); perror standardizes the error message, can give you free localization, reports the system error, and is generally a good idea.

You declare a buffer pointer:
char *buffer;

but you don't point it at anything. For a small-ish buffer that is of a constant fixed size, you might want to change this to:
#define BUFF_SIZE 100
...
char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

Get rid of the variable n. Read the data with:
while (fgets (buffer, BUFF_SIZE, in1 ) !=  NULL)

Alternatively, if you might have very large buffers and don't want to consume stack for it, you should allocate a buffer from the heap. Keep the variable n. Then:
int n = 100;
char *buffer = malloc(n);
if (buffer == NULL) {
  // print error and probably exit
}

Then, at the end of the function:
free(buffer);

This will fix your immediate problem. But don't forget what some of the comments have also said, like Weather Vane pointing out that you detect fopen errors but continue execution. You should exit the program, or at least return a bad status to your caller.

Thank you, beginner mistake, learn again something.
